# Update Panel AsyncPostback Trigger not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows, internet-explorer, updatepanel

In my application **the AsyncPostback trigger** of update panel is **not** working in **IE 9 and IE 10** but working in IE 8 and postbacktrigger is also working in all IE version.

This give error

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed.

I have tried several thing before posting this issue :

- async = true in page tag
- registering the postback on page load (this cannot be used as update panel is throughout the system)
- allowing async in web config

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                                   <ContentTemplate>
                                       <cc:BinNumberMultiDropDown runat="server" TabIndex="3"    ProgramTrue="true" ID="ddl_bin_number"
                                           CssClass="multiselect">
                                       </cc:BinNumberMultiDropDown>
                                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_ddl_bin_number" runat="server"    ControlToValidate="ddl_bin_number" ValidationGroup="vg_rate"    Display="Dynamic"
                                           SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                   </ContentTemplate>
                                   <Triggers>
                                       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_program" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                   </Triggers>
                               </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please suggest me with the solution

**I also found that this error is appearing only in Winodws 8 systems**

Comment: can you post your code sample ?

Comment: where is your ddl_program ? is it dropdown outside the update panel ?

Comment: its outside the update panel

Comment: Is there any ajax/xhr request raised from browser? If so what is response when AsyncPostback doesn't works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using .net framework 4.0, there is some issues in framework 4.0 with windows 8, if possible you can try with converting you application in framework 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainContainerUpdatePanel" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your browser definition files are updated on the server, there are a number of problems related to javascript postback handling that are caused by .Net incorrectly detecting new versions of IE.
There are a number of hotfix patches to update the files, see Scott Hanselmann's blog for further details :

> http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

and

> http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedjavascriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.asp

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. I analysed the cause & find many good post about the cause of problem & how to resolve it. One of them is found on [Eilon Lipton's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx):

> **Why do I keeping getting a PageRequestManagerParserErrorException?**
>
> Well, chances are you're doing one of the things mentioned in the
>   error message. Here are the most common reasons and why they don't
>   work:
>
> 1.**Calls to Response.Write()**:
>
> By calling `Response.Write()` directly you are bypassing the normal
>   rendering mechanism of ASP.NET controls. The bits you write are going
>   straight out to the client without further processing (well,
>   mostly...). This means that `UpdatePanel` can't encode the data in its
>   special format.
>
> **2.Response filters:**
>
> Similar to `Response.Write()`, response filters can change the
>   rendering in such a way that the `UpdatePanel` won't know.
>
> **3.HttpModules:** Again, the same deal as `Response.Write()` and response filters.
>
> **4.Server trace is enabled:** If I were going to implement trace again, I'd do it differently. `Trace` is effectively written out using
>   `Response.Write()`, and as such messes up the special format that we
>   use for `UpdatePanel`.
>
> **5. Calls to Server.Transfer():** Unfortunately, there's no way to detect that `Server.Transfer()` was called. This means that
>   `UpdatePanel` can't do anything intelligent when someone calls
>   `Server.Transfer()`. The response sent back to the client is the HTML
>   markup from the page to which you transferred. Since its HTML and not
>   the special format, it can't be parsed, and you get the error. How do
>   I avoid getting a `PageRequestManagerParserErrorException`?
>
> **To start with, don't do anything from the preceding list! Here's a matching list of how to avoid a given error (when possible):**
>
> **Calls to Response.Write():** Place an `<asp:Label>` or similar control on your page and set its Text property. The added benefit is
>   that your pages will be valid HTML. When using `Response.Write()` you
>   typically end up with pages that contain invalid markup.
>
> **Response filters:** The fix might just be to not use the filter. They're not used very often anyway. If possible, filter things at the
>   control level and not at the response level.
>
> **HttpModules:** Same as response filters.
>
> **Server trace is enabled:** Use some other form of tracing, such as writing to a log file, the Windows event log, or a custom mechanism.
>
> **Calls to Server.Transfer():** I'm not really sure why people use `Server.Transfer()` at all. Perhaps it's a legacy thing from Classic
>   ASP. I'd suggest using `Response.Redirect()` with query string
>   parameters or cross-page posting.
>
> **Another way** to avoid the parse error is to do a regular postback instead of an `asynchronous postback`. For example, if you have a
>   button that absolutely must do a `Server.Transfer()`, make it do
>   regular postbacks. There are a number of ways of doing this:
>
> - The easiest is to simply place the button outside of any    `UpdatePanels`. Unfortunately the layout of your page might not allow 
>     for this.
> - Add a `PostBackTrigger` to your `UpdatePanel` that points at the button.    This works great if the button is declared statically
>     through markup    on the page.
> - Call `ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl()` and pass in the button    in question. This is the best solution for controls that are
>     added    dynamically, such as those inside a repeating template.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
  scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(btn.Your-BUTTON-HERE');
  //Further code goes here....
}
```

Put this and it will work or if you have multiple update panels ? let us know

Comment: I cannot do this because this will require massive change in whole application which is not worthy